# ObservableValue change listeners: how to access

Tags: javafx, changelistener

I'm new to JavaFX and have started converting custom components written in Swing. As a best practice I have always checked whether an event listener (PropertyChangeListener, MouseListener, ActionListener etc.) is already included in the target object's listeners to make sure the same listener isn't being added twice. I'm trying to do the same with JavaFX but can't find any way to access the list of listeners (for example, to run a list.contains(listener) check).

Am I looking for something that doesn't exist? If so, is there some good reason why JavaFX doesn't include this feature (IMHO it should)?

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to access those in JavaFX. Can you give an example of why you need them (or think you do)? I've never come across a need to do that.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I'm trying to avoid registering the same object as a listener more than once. A use case where this can happen follows in an additional comment, but believe me it is possible and when it does the event gets fired to the listener as many times as the listener appears in the event listeners list. Inefficient and unnecessary because a listener almost always (99.9999999% of the time) needs to handle the event

Comment: Yes, I understood that: I've just never come across a situation where you would not know if the listener was already registered. That's the use case I was wondering about.

Comment: .. handle the event only once. Also - and this caught my eye - the JavaFX documentation specifically states that if a listener is registered more than once, then invoking [list].removeListener() removes only the first entry in the list. In other words, if you think you've removed a listener and it's somehow been added twice to the list, you might wonder why the listener still handles the event.

Comment: USE CASE - In a composite component that includes a text field and a button, the button may be positioned above the text field or to the left. Both components are have a BorderPane as their parent. If the button appears above (BorderPane.TOP) the button length should not stretch to match the text field (BorderPane.CENTER) so I have an event handler that calculates the button's right-side padding value. The event handler catches changes in width to keep things in sync. If the button is on the left, this process isn't necessary, and in that case I would like to disconnect the event handler.

Comment: But in that use case, you clearly always know if the handler is registered or not without having to query the list of handlers.

Comment: A simple solution is to keep track of when everything happens, but I'm lazy and worked out a solution a long time ago where I use a utility method to check a listener list EVERY time before a listener gets added. That solves the problem without my having to keep track.

Comment: You may probably just always remove a listener before adding it. From the [`removeListener` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#removeListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-): *If the given listener has not been previously registered (i.e. it was never added) then this method call is a no-op.* They do it like that in the framework, e.g. in the `com.sun.javafx.binding.ContentBinding.bind()` methods.

Comment: It's kind of moot because the answer is that there is no way to access that list in JavaFX, but I just don't buy that you ever need this (I've been working with Swing and/or JavaFX since 1998, and I've never needed it). Your UI (component) is always, in some sense, a view of some data; so whether or not a listener is added is always a function of the state of your data. In your use case, the listener is added if the custom component is oriented vertically, and not added if it is oriented horizontally.

Comment: I saw that as well and had the same idea, your confirmation is helpful :). FWIW - I'm new to JavaFX and coming from Swing, and IMHO Swing (still) does some things better, for example the point in my question. JavaFX provides a ton of info not available before, not all of it useful, yet something like making the listener list accessible (as in Swing) doesn't happen when it would've been so easy to make that info available. Everything is based on lists, why not expose a [list].contains(listener) method?

Comment: @James_D - thanks for your comments. What I'm trying to accomplish is (i) have the listener removed when button is on the left so the handler code doesn't even get invoked, but (ii) have the listener restored if the button is positioned at the top.

Comment: Yes, again, I had understood that. I just don't see a need to access the list of listeners in order to accomplish that. See answer for a concrete example of why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in the public API to access the list of listeners for a property in JavaFX.

I'm not sure I ever really see a need for this. Your code is in control of when the listeners are added and removed, so you basically always "know" when the listeners have been added. In a broader sense, your UI or UI component is always a presentation of some form of data, and so whether or not the listener is registered is just a function of those data.

For a concrete example, consider the use case cited in the comments:

```
public class CustomComponent extends BorderPane {

    private final Button button = new Button("Button");
    private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    private final ObjectProperty<Orientation> orientation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<Orientation> orientationProperty() {
        return orientation ;
    }

    public final Orientation getOrientation() {
        return orientationProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setOrientation(Orientation orientation) {
        orientationProperty().set(orientation);
    }

    public CustomControl(Orientation orientation) {
        setCenter(textField);

        ChangeListener<Number> widthBindingListener = (obs, oldWidth, newWidth) ->
            button.setPrefWidth(newWidth.doubleValue());

        orientationProperty().addListener((obs, oldOrientation, newOrientation) -> {
            if (newOrientation == Orientation.HORIZONTAL) {
                textField.widthProperty().removeListener(widthBindingListener);
                button.setPrefWidth(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                setTop(null);
                setLeft(button);
            } else {
                textField.widthProperty().addListener(widthBindingListener);
                button.setPrefWidth(textField.getWidth());
                setLeft(null);
                setTop(button);
            }
        }

        setOrientation(orientation);

    }

    public CustomControl() {
        this(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    }

    // other methods etc....
}
```

In this example, you would probably just use a binding instead of the listeners:

```
button.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings
    .when(orientationProperty().isEqualTo(Orientation.HORIZONTAL))
    .then(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)
    .otherwise(textField.widthProperty()));
```

but that doesn't demonstrate the concept...

Note that, as in @Clemens comment, you can always ensure a listener is only ever registered once with the idiom:

```
textField.widthProperty().removeListener(widthBindingListener);
textField.widthProperty().addListener(widthBindingListener);
```

but this just seems to me not to be very good practice: the `removeListener` involves iterating through the list of listeners (and in the case where it's not already added, the *entire* list of listeners). This iteration is unnecessary because the information is already available elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, had to do a double take while reading through your example b/c its resemblance to my own code is uncanny. Your suggestion re binding came to me while out for a walk, it's probably the most efficient solution for this particular case. Reason for original question is an event model developed while working with Swing, it's the ancestor for a number of other models and works very well. In switching over to JavaFX I'm trying to keep the good stuff from Swing (at least the processes) and translate them into the new format. When that's not possible I wonder why.

Comment: I think we probably disagree on whether exposing the list of listeners is part of Swing's "good stuff". To me it's a bit of a code smell (["Inappropriate intimacy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)). If you have `addListener` and `removeListener` methods, why do you need to expose the list; or, conversely, if you are exposing the list, why have the additional methods? There was an interesting interview with Richard Bair (lead architect of JavaFX and prominent on Swing) where he said "in Swing we broke a lot of people's code". (continued...)

Comment: I think JavaFX, while very far from perfect, improves a lot on Swing in terms of good OOP (mostly on concepts understood between the first releases of each): you will see many more `final` methods in JavaFX that are designed to enforce class invariants, and you will find you can write JavaFX with far less reliance on subclassing existing classes, and (pertinent to your question) less exposure of properties that are really implementation details. You may have to work a bit harder to code around that, but you end up with better code in the end imho.

Comment: re your question "... why do you need to expose the list; or, conversely, if you are exposing the list why have the additional methods?" In my earlier Swing work on custom components there were instances when listeners needed to be disconnected to change the value in that particular instance without notifying the listeners, which were almost always (99.9999% of the time) external to the component. After the change they would be reconnected. This was dictated by design factors. Other designs wouldn't require this step, but came with other costs. (continued...)

Comment: Regarding "... exposing the list, [then] why the additional methods [add/removeListener]", it must be noted that the Swing event models make listeners accessible as an ARRAY, .. not a list, and arrays are IMHO infinitely more difficult to access and handle than lists. Even converting the array to a list doesn't mean that changes made to the list will be reflected in the array of listeners that's maintained by the component or the component's event managing support class. Thanks again for your input.